# How to avoid Android TalkBack reading SwitchCompat TextOn/TextOff

Tags: android, talkback

I have a `SwitchCompat` with a text that I set via `SwitchCompat.setText()`.
In my case this text is only "On" or "Off".

The problem is Android TalkBack will then read for example "On ON, Switch, double tap to...".
Also `setShowText(false)` doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use:

```
mToggle.setTextOff("");
mToggle.setTextOn("");
```

Then only the text you set via setText() is being read. Don't know if this strange behavior is a bug or works as designed, it doesn't seem right to me though.

Comment: in my case works with a space between, like mToggle.setTextOff(" ").

Comment: What if there is no text? Just a simple switch.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use .setContentDescription() instead.

This is the method primarily used for accessibility support. You can read its documentation here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)

Also, following accessibility guidelines, you shouldn't get rid of the actionable text provided i.e. "ON double tap to.."

Hope this helps!

Comment: setContentDescription also doesn't work out because it ends in talking for example: Off OFF, ContentDescription, Switch, double tap to toggle.